# Объединенный запрос mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, select, update, php7

Добрый день!

В таблице `or_auth` должен хранится `ip` и `email`, у них есть поле `col` в котором хранится число и поле `date` - для срока хранения на 1 час, причем вставку `ip` и вставку `email` в таблицу нужно выполнить отдельными строками. Т.е., если существует уже `ip`, то в поле `col` по данному `ip` прибавляется единица и обновляется время, если такого `ip` нет - записывается данный `ip` со значением в поле `col = 1` и записывается время. Затем, нужно здесь же проверить, а есть ли такой емайл в этой же таблице, если нет, то надо вставить его отдельной строкой в эту же таблицу со значением в поле `col = 1` и записать время ему, если есть то просто в поле `col` по данному емайлу прибавляется также единица и обновляется время.

Вот, что я пробую:

```
//Переменную $email получаю выше
$logip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];//Получаем ip
$time_insert = time()+3600;//Для срока хранения в БД на 1 час
$logcol = 1;//Изначально поле col будет равно 1
$query = "(SELECT `col` FROM `or_auth` WHERE `ip` = '$logip') 
            UNION
          (SELECT `email` FROM `or_auth` WHERE `email` = '$email')";
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);             
   if(isset($row['email'])){//Обновляем данные емайла, если он уже существует в БД   
      if($row['col']<5){//Здесь нужно только у email проверять, но не знаю как
         mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `or_auth` SET `date`='$time_insert', `col`=`col`+1 
                                   WHERE `email` = '$email'");  
      }else{
         mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `or_auth` SET `date`='$time_insert' 
                                   WHERE `email` = '$email'");
      }    
   }else{//Если в БД еще нет такого емайла, записываем его
      mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `or_auth` (`email`, `date`, `col`)
                                   VALUES ('$email', '$time_insert', '$logcol')");
   }           
   if($row['col']<5){//Здесь нужно только у ip проверять, но не знаю как
      mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `or_auth` SET `date` = '$time_insert', `col` = `col` + 1 
                                    WHERE `ip` = '$logip'");
   }else{
                mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `or_auth` SET `date` = '$time_insert' WHERE `ip` = '$logip'");
   }
}
else{//Если ip и email нет в БД, то надо их записать отдельными строками
   $query = "INSERT INTO `or_auth` (`ip`, `email`, `date`, `col`)
                VALUES ('$logip', '', '$time_insert', '$logcol'),('', '$email', '$time_insert', '$logcol')";
   $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
}
```

Первый раз ip и емайл если таких нет в БД еще, заносятся в БД отлично, но последующие разы емайл вставляется заново, но у ip отлично обновляется поле col и время, а емайл один и тот же записывается каждый раз отдельной строкой, как уже написал выше. Комментарии к коду местами написал.

Надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

Comment: Или может сделать два запроса SELECT для ip и для email отдельно? Зато будет известно с чем работать, нет такого ip - записали в БД, если есть выполняем все операции с ним, и точно также по емайлу.